# Total points for each student in Google spreadsheet or excel

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets

I am in the process of creating a Google form, which students will fill out after attending an event. Based on the event they attend, I will be assigning points to them and this form can be submitted through the whole year.

Is there a way to get a total number of points for each students, since they'll be submitting the form multiple times, I need a way to tally up the points for each students

Example spreadsheet goo.gl/1aunYg

- Sam   | 2
- Jon   | 2
- Mike  | 2
- Don   | 2
- Sam   | 3
- Sam   | 1
- Jon   | 2
- Mike  | 1

Total for Sam: ???
Total for Jon: ???
Total for Mike: ???
Total for Don: ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In google spreadsheets, assuming you have the names in Col A and the scores in Col B, you can also try:

```
=query(A2:B; "select A, sum(B) where A <>'' group by A label sum(B) 'Totals' ")
```

This should output an array of unique names and the summed scores.

Comment: That will create an extra (empty) row between the header row (with the word 'sum' in it) and the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Google Spreadsheet see [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)

In Excel you could do something like ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list on Name (Home>Sort & Filter)

Add a heading for the columns

Apply SubTotals (Data>Subtotal in the Outline group) at each change in Name and using the function Sum.

[image: Example]

You can then hide/show individuals using the controls on the LH side.